# Bootstrap modal Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Trying to work with bootstrap I am getting an error written in title

my code

```
function closeDialog () {
    $('#windowTitleDialog').modal('hide'); 
};
```

these are the files included

```
  <link href="http://static.scripting.com/github/bootstrap2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://static.scripting.com/github/bootstrap2/js/jquery.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  <script src="{{=URL(request.application,'static','js/bootstrap-transition.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="http://static.scripting.com/github/bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"src="{{=URL(request.application,'static','js/modal.js')}}"></script>
```

any suggestions??

Comment: is your `#windowTitleDialog` an initialized bootstrap modal?  If you include all your html and jQuery it will be easier to look into it for you.

Comment: I used bootstrap 3.smth and it kind of works :)

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact problem.
The solution was quite simple after all:

**It turned out, that I had included jQuery twice**.

After removing the superfluous jQuery, the modal started to work as expected. So

```
$('#theModal').modal('hide')
```

actually closed the dialog.

Comment: Wow, I did the exact same thing. Thank you for answering your own question. I was completely stumped as to why it wasn't working.